# find all ":)" that are not surrounded by any character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to change all ":)" (without quotes) to pictures. To make a match, a smiley must be surrounded by spaces (or be at the beginning or the end of a string).

My attempt: `/(?:^|\s)\:\)(?:$|\s)/g`

> if a smiley is (at the beginning of a string or has a white-space before it) and (is at the end of a string or has a white-space after it);

A string like that works fine: ":) x :) x :)"
but such string does not: ":) :) :) :)" (every second smiley is changed).

As I understand, the first smiley is matched with the space after it and the next smiley is neither at the beginning of a string or has a white-space anymore. I'm new to regular expressions and can't figure out how to fix my logic :)

P.S. maybe there is a shortcut to find a pattern that is not surrounded by any character? (`\b` and `\B` would not work for that)

Comment: I currently neither know the syntax nor if it is supported by js, but there is look ahead and look behind in regexp.

Comment: @t.niese JS doesn't support negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the regex

```
(?:\s|^):\)(?=\s|$)
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/zY9xA3/2

**Problem with `/(?:^|\s)\:\)(?:$|\s)/g`**

- The `\s` after `:)` is consumed by the regex engine that for the second `:)` we cannot have a presceding `\s`

**Solution**

Use a positive look ahead so that the the space after is not consumed by the regex.

- `(?=\s|$)` look ahead asserts that `:)` is followed by space or end of string. But wont consume the character.

**Changes made**

- `\:` to `:` you need not escape the the `:`
- `(?:$|\s)` non capturing group to positive look ahead `(?=\s|$)`

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware about looking ahead. This regex works as expected.